# Unity C# understanding reference to clone not prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

SO i know this question has been asked 10,000 times before.  But I just cant seem to grasp the answer.  I've been building some prototype game designs in Unity for a little bit now and am learning a TON from using Visual Studios auto complete to find out what stuff does.
   So I am having a very hard time  grasping the prefab code stuff.  For a quick test to post here I build a magnet that picks up a car when "Left Control" is pressed and drops on release.  The issue is the magnet picks up a random version of the prefab when I drop a few in the scene .  How can I reference the single game object attached to the script vs. the prefab.

ADDING FOR CLARITY

So here is the main problem.  The magnet will pick up any random object tagged "Car" it will not pick up on the one inside the trigger zone. 
How can i make it only pickup the "Car" inside the trigger?

Here is the Magnet Code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
//This Goes on the Object that is to be moved by a magnet
public class CraneMagnet : MonoBehaviour
{

    private CraneTrigger craneTrigger;
    public string getTag = "";
    void Start()
    {
        craneTrigger = FindObjectOfType<CraneTrigger>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == getTag)
        {
            craneTrigger.canPickup = true;
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the object picked up by the magnet

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TESTObjectMovedByTag : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool liftObject = false;
    Rigidbody objectRigidbody;

    // strings for get objects of type to declare in the inspector;
    public string getTag = "";

    void Start()
    {
        objectRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        PickUpObject();
    }

    void PickUpObject()
    {
        if (liftObject)
        {
            objectRigidbody.isKinematic = true;// so the gravity will affect the object
            transform.parent = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(getTag).transform;// make the object child of the magnet 
        }

        if(!liftObject)
        {
            objectRigidbody.isKinematic = false;// so gravity will not affect the object
            transform.parent = null;// remove the magnet parent
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you clarify a bit.

Comment: Sure.  So I created a prefab with a Car and it is tagged Car.  I created a box with a trigger collider tagged "Crane"  The objectMovedByTag script grabs ahold of the getTag which is named "Crane" in the inspector.  But if the magnet is on any car taged item it will pick up a random car not the one under the trigger colllider

Comment: Your question title asks about `Instantiate`, but your code doesn't ever call it. You need to work on the title and body of your question to make it clearer as to what it is you are actually asking.

Comment: Title changed.    Is the question not clear? should i reword it all?

Comment: I still don't get your problem. You want to know which car was picked up?

Comment: The problem is that when you handle the collision in the `CraneMagnet` object, you need to store a reference to the object that caused that collision. As it is, you are just grabbing the first object in your scene that matches the given tag and hoping it's the correct one, and chances are good that it won't be.

Comment: Right  That is exactly what is happening.  I have similar issues with a few different scripts butI cant quite grasp how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I figured out in this instance how to make this happen only using the CraneMagnet script
For anyone interested here is the code to pick up a tagged Rigidbody from a different object

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CraneMagnet : MonoBehaviour
    {
    private CraneTrigger craneTrigger;// This is calling only for controls
    public string getTag = "";// Define the tag in the inpector
    private Rigidbody objectPickedUp;
    [HideInInspector] public bool canLift = false;
    [HideInInspector] private bool isLifted = false;// only exists so the objectPickedUp cant be called until is exists 
    void Start()
    {
        craneTrigger = FindObjectOfType<CraneTrigger>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //call PickUpObject() in the control script
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == getTag)
        {
            objectPickedUp = other.attachedRigidbody;// make the triggered RididBody become objectPIckedUP 
            craneTrigger.canPickup = true;
        }

    }
    public void PickUpObject()
    {
        if (canLift)
        {
            objectPickedUp.transform.parent = transform;// object becomes child of magnet 
            isLifted = true;
            objectPickedUp.isKinematic = true;// so object can be moved easier
        }
        if (!canLift && isLifted)
        {
            objectPickedUp.isKinematic = false;// so gravity will take over the fall
            objectPickedUp.transform.parent = null;//the picked up object looses magnet parent
            isLifted = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To explain: `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag` will find *a* game object with that tag. If there is more than one, there is no guarantee that it is any given object, only that it DOES have the tag. This is why this answer uses trigger zones to figure out which *object* it should be picking up (the one that entered the trigger) rather than searching the whole scene for any object with the same tag as the one that entered the zone.